# @mswjs/data question: why does RTK-Query sandbox example need separately handcoded POST and PUT mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, rtk-query, msw

This is a question about the default behaviour of @mswjs/data.toHandlers function using this example with @mswjs/data to create mocks for RTK-Query calls.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/examples/query/react/mutations?from-embed

the file src/mocks/db.ts creates a mock database using @mswjs/data and defines default http mock responses using `...db.post.toHandlers('rest')` but fails to work if I remove the additional PUT and POST mocks.

My understanding is that @mswjs/data toHandlers() function provides PUT and POST mock API calls for a defined database (in this case Posts) by default according to the github documentation so I am seeking advice to understand better why toHandlers does not work for PUT and POST in this example. i.e. if i remove PUT and POST mock API calls they fail.

What do the manual PUT and POST API mocks do that the default toHandlers dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to state that `.toHandlers()` generates both `POST /posts` and `PUT /posts/:id` request handlers. The RTK-Query example adds those handlers explicitly for the following reasons:

1. To emulate flaky error behavior by returning an error response based on the `Math.random()` value in the handler.
2. To *set the `id` primary key to `nanoid()`*.

Adding a post fails if you remove the explicit `POST /posts` handler because the model definition for `post` *does not define the initial value for the `id` primary key*. You cannot create an entity without providing a primary key to it, which the example does not:

```
// PostManager.tsx
// The "post" state only contains the name of the new post.
const [post, setPost] = useState<Pick<Post, "name">>(initialValue);

// Only the "post" state is passed to the code that dispatches the
// "POST /posts" request handled by MSW.
await addPost(post).unwrap();
```

If we omit the random error behavior, I think the example should've used `nanoid` as the initial value of the `id` property in the model description:

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const db = factory({
  post: {
-   id: primaryKey(String),
+   id: primaryKey(nanoid),
    name: String
  }
});
```

This way you would be able to create new posts by supplying the `name` only. The value of the `id` primary key would be generated using the value getter—the `nanoid` function.

The post edit operation functions correctly even if you remove the explicit `PUT /posts/:id` request handler because, unlike the `POST` handler, the `PUT`  one is only there to implement a flaky error behavior (the edited post id is provided in the path parameters: `req.params.id`).